# AWS Redis Cluster MOVED Error using redis node library

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-memory-db

I have created a Redis MemoryDB cluster with 2 nodes in AWS:
[image]

I connect to it using [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) node library v4.0.0 like this:

```
import { createCluster } from 'redis';
(async () => {
    const REDIS_USERNAME = 'test-username';
    const REDIS_PASSWORD = 'test-pass';
    const cluster = createCluster({
        rootNodes: [
            {
                url: `rediss://node1.amazonaws.com:6379`,
            },
            {
                url: `rediss://node2.amazonaws.com:6379`,
            },
        ],
        defaults: {
            url: `rediss://cluster.amazonaws.com:6379`,
            username: REDIS_USERNAME,
            password: REDIS_PASSWORD,
        }
    });
    cluster.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Cluster Error', err));
    await cluster.connect();
    console.log('connected to cluster...');
    await cluster.set('key', 'value');
    const value = await cluster.get('key');
    console.log('Value', value);
    await cluster.disconnect();
})();
```

But sometimes I get the error `ReplyError: MOVED 12539 rediss://node2.amazonaws.com:6379` and I cannot get the value from the key.

Do you have any idea if there is something wrong with the configuration of the cluster or with the code using redis node library?

**Edit:**
I tried it with [ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) library and it works, so it's something wrong with the [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) library.

**Node.js Version:** 16

**Redis Server Version:** 6

Comment: Are you sure the URLs you're using is `redis` & not `rediss` ?

Comment: I use `rediss`. The second `s` stands for connection using tls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created an [issue](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/1782) to redis library, so it's going to be solved soon with [this PR](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/pull/1827).